# returning byte array from stored procedure using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have a stored procedure which returns single column of datatype image.stored procedure is added to linq to sql class.how can i create byte array from the stored procedure using linq to sql.

stored procedure is

```
create procedure selecttempimage
@user_id bigint
as
begin
select user_image from Temp_Image where users_id=@user_id
end
```

linq to sql generated method is

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.selecttempimage")]
    public ISingleResult<selecttempimageResult> selecttempimage([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(DbType="BigInt")] System.Nullable<long> user_id)
{
IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), user_id);
return ((ISingleResult<selecttempimageResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to do this specifically by LINQ to SQL ? I used similar field and got byte array in the Select SP, but not via LINQ

Comment: What is the signature of your LINQ-to-SQL method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, if your Linq2Sql context is called MyDbDataContext:

```
using(var context = new MyDbDataContext())
{
    var byte_array = context.selecttempimage(user_id).SingleOrDefault();
    //...do something with byte_array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string givenId = "...";

var images = from Temp_Image in db.Users where users_id == givenId select user_image;

List<byte[]> image_byte_arr = new List<byte[]>();

foreach(image in images)
   image_byte_arr.Add((byte[])image.user_image);
```

Comment: Formatting Tip: once you indent 4 spaces (or one tab) there's no need for the backticks. Cheers mate. Keith.

Comment: Ya.. somehow i wasnt getting the formatting, so applied the ticks. Now i see that it takes a while for formatting to show. :) Cheers!